# Forwarding methods to a wrapped class

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I'd like to attach some extra functionality (logging more or less) to methods of another class, but with the caveat that I can't subclass them, since I do not have control over the instantiation of the original class, but I can forward an object with the same duck typing. In other words, I'd like to prepend some code to a few methods while forwarding everything else to the original class instance.

An example of what I'm trying to accomplish would be something like the following:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)

class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

    @classmethod
    def bar():
        print("bar")

b = B()
a = A(b)
a.foo() # prints "foo"
a.bar() # Fails (tries to pass the self parameter to bar())
```

Except that the method above fails for class methods, so it won't do it in my case. Is there a way to forward calls like this in a way that also works with class methods and static methods?

Comment: There's probably a neater way, but can't you simply call a pre-processor function that later calls/handles the return value of the actual intended function?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm feeding the class into a framework, so I have no control over how anything is getting called.

Comment: That's useful information ^^

Comment: Well, with the above code, you would not be able to do b.bar() either, as bar has to get self as a parameter. Add self as a parameter to bar method and you will be able to do access bar from a just fine.

Comment: Oops... I forgot to put "cls" there. It does look like this works in all cases.